# How can I make the text automatically appear in the search bar?

Tags: javascript, function, object, web

There is an object with keys whose values are text, and this text should appear in the placeholder of the search page on the site. The first key is written one letter at a time until the whole word is created, and then, one letter at a time, it is completely deleted, and the second key is written in the same way in placeholder. The dialing speed does not matter.

I am enclosing my work. Now the problem is that all the keys are written, but they must take turns, deleting the previous one by letter.

```js
let types={
    phrase1:"Words",
    phrase2:"has been",
    phrase3:"deleted",
};

function writer() {
    let curr = 0;
    let text = Object.values(types)
    let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('topnav');

    elem.textContent += text.charAt(curr);

    curr++
        if (curr < text.length )
            window.setInterval(writer,60);

}
writer();
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <input type="text" placeholder=" ">
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide more details. you want each character of each sentence printed individually? at what interval? what is the desired interval between the sentences transition?

Comment: @vsync Yes, they should be written one by one, deleting the previous one. Any time of writing and deletion. Already correcting

Comment: @AlexLemeshev so only one character at a time?

Comment: @Alex like one argument. Writes, for example, "words" and deletes, then writes "has been" and again deletes.Sorry if I didn't write the assignment exactly

Comment: @Alex This is something that looks like it.

Comment: I can clarify the task even more. If this task has not bored you yet. It would be easier if I knew English better.

Comment: @AlexLemeshev clarify it and the best would be if you do it directly in your question and not here in the comments

Comment: @Alex Updated. I hope it will be better now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227211/discussion-between-alex-and-alex-lemeshev).

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

- call setTimeout() because it will call the method once whereas setIntervall() will call it repetitive what doesn't make sense here because you will call it in your next function call again.
- use recursion to get the next word of your array

Defined three cases here

1. `current letter < wordsArray.length` apply method on the same element of the array
2. When 1 is false and `value < wordsArray` apply method on the next array element `writer(value+1)`
3. 1 and 2 are false then print out the content of the array as string

```js
let types = {
  phrase1: "Words",
  phrase2: "has been",
  phrase3: "deleted",
};

var curr = 0;

function writer(value) {
  let inp = document.getElementById("text");


  let wordArray = Object.values(types)
  let sentence = wordArray[value];
  inp.placeholder = sentence.charAt(curr);
  curr++;

  if (curr < sentence.length){
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      writer(value);
    }, 500);
  }else if(value < wordArray.length-1){
  window.setTimeout(function() {
      curr = 0;
      inp.placeholder = " ";
      writer(value+1);
    }, 500)
  }else {
   inp.placeholder = wordArray.join().replaceAll(",", " ");
  }


}
writer(0);
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <input id="text" type="text" placeholder=" ">
</div>
```

Comment: It's always good to provide some explanation with answers rather than just a code dump. That way the OP understands better what you've proposing.

Comment: `let elem` is obsolete now.

Comment: @Reyno removed it

Answer (score 0):

I've made a demo, from the **very little** you could piece together from your question. You really didn't specify anything... BUT I would like to add that the `types` variable should be an `Array` and not an `Object` which makes it much easier to work with. Nonetheless, I did work with your provided code:

```js
const types = {
    phrase1:"Words",
    phrase2:"has been",
    phrase3:"deleted",
}

const inputElm = document.querySelector('.topnav > input')

function iteratePlaceholder(place = 1) {
  inputElm.placeholder = types[`phrase${place||1}`];

  // call this function again only if "place" is less than the length of keys (3)
  (place < Object.keys(types).length) && setTimeout(iteratePlaceholder, 500, ++place)
}

iteratePlaceholder()
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <input type="text" placeholder=" ">
</div>
```